# How to run composer without xdebug (when installed with homebrew)

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew, xdebug

If you've installed PHP & composer w/ homebrew and have xdebug enabled, you may see the following error:

> You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug

There's an [open issue on homebrew-php](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2937) but no official resolution yet. That said, there is a temporary fix (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary fix:

#### 1. Open `/usr/local/bin/composer` in your editor of choice.

#### 2. Update this file with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEMP_PATH="$( mktemp --tmpdir --suffix=.ini -t php-no-debug.XXXXXXX )"
FILES="$( /usr/bin/env php -r 'echo php_ini_loaded_file() . "\n" . str_replace(",","", php_ini_scanned_files());' )"
cat $FILES | sed '/xdebug/d' > "$TEMP_PATH"

/usr/bin/env php -n -c "$TEMP_PATH" -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.1.1/libexec/composer.phar "$@"

rm -f "$TEMP_PATH"
```

**You'll need to replace** `/usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.1.1/libexec/composer.phar` with the path in your existing `/usr/local/bin/composer` file (it will differ depending on what version of composer you have installed).

Hopefully by the next time you update composer there will be an official fix. If not, you will have to re-apply this change after each update.

**For the curious:** This works by creating a temporary file, copying the contents of your existing `php.ini` and all included `ini` files into it, but excluding any line that contains `xdebug`, then using that new file for composer. Once composer finishes running, that file is deleted.